# Provided $A \cup B = \Omega$, Show that $\nu^{+}(F)=\nu(B \cap F)$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, measure-theory

I am currently working on proving part of the Hahn-Jordan decomposition as stated in my textbook and have a question about the provided hint:

> Let $\nu$ be a bounded signed measure. There are disjoint sets $A,B$ such that $A \cup B = \Omega$ and $\nu^{+}(F)=\nu(B \cap F)$.

The hint is as follows: for $d\nu=hd|\nu|$ and $|h|=1$ let $A  = \{h=-1\}$, $B = \{h = 1\}$ and observe that $\nu^{+}(F) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{F}(1+h)d|\nu|$.

I want the prove the question on my own, but I am unsure why $\nu^{+}(F) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{F}(1+h)d|\nu|$ is true as given in the hint. However, I can see that $\chi_{B}h=\frac{1}{2}(1+h)$. Can anyone clarify why $\nu^{+}(F)$ can be written this way so I can use this hint in my proof?